# Polar map from existing Cartesian coordinates and phi values in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a polar colour heat map for a set of coordinates (coor) and corresponding phi values. I have used the tripcolor function as follows:

```
plt.tripcolor(coor[:, 0], coor[:, 1], phi, shading=shading, cmap=cmap, edgecolor="face")
plt.show()
```

This is the result that I got:
[PlotMesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3ypH.png)

Is there a way to make the outer grid circular?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to create a triangulation from the coordinates:

```
import matplotlib.tri as tri
triang = tri.Triangulation(coor[:, 0], coor[:, 1])
plt.tripcolor(triang, phi, shading=shading, cmap=cmap, edgecolor="face")
```